# How can I send an AWS SQS message with C# with a custom timeout?

Tags: c#, amazon-sqs

Here's my basic code to send an SQS message from C# using the AWS .NET SDK. **How can I give the message a different timeout other than the queue default?**

```
    public async Task PostMessage(Uri queueUrl, string body)
    {
        var request = new SendMessageRequest()
                          {
                              MessageBody = body, 
                              QueueUrl = queueUrl.ToString(),
                          };
        var result = await this.client.SendMessageAsync(request);
    }
```

I [can](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AboutVT.html#AboutVT-extending-message-visibility-timeout) send a separate API call to extend the timeout of an in-flight message. But I'd like to do this at the time of creation if that's practical to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with C# API or with any other API. Message visibility timeout is set globally on a queue.

I would suggest to create 2 queues. One for short tasks and one for long tasks. This way you can set different visibility timeouts on the queues.